# Leiningen Uberjar different results from lein run

Tags: clojure, leiningen

My application runs when I run it in the clojure repl or using leiningen repl  but when i create a jar using uberjar and run the application it only reads the first 2 records of my collection.

I tracked it down to pmap so I created the simplest possible use of pmap and it gets wierder.
why does this work

```
(ns ktest.core
    (:gen-class))
(defn -main []
  (println (pmap identity (range 20))))
```

but not this

```
(ns ktest.core
        (:gen-class))
    (defn -main []
       (pmap #(println %) (range 20)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have been bitten by "the lazy bug". pmap creates the sequence that when read will compute the results. when you run this with the `println` it reads the results so it can print them, thus triggering the evaluation. In this case you can fix this will `doall` or `dorun`. If you only need the printing side effects of running it then choose `dorun`, if you need to do something with this result then choose `doall` which keeps the results in memory.

```
(dorun (pmap #(println %) (range 20)))
```

a couple items get printed because of [chunked sequences](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/12/clojure-11-rc1-transients). see this Jira issue for details on [pmap and chunked sequences](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-862).

Comment: On a general note, we should not do any side-effect operations in functions like pmap, map etc

Comment: @Cubic: Because these functional are based on FP concepts and hence you should do any side-effects on your risk as it can lead to race-conditions kind of problem

Comment: The only undesirable result I see from side effects in pmap is that the order will not be consistent, some threads may finish first. In general the most common side effect problem is side effects running multiple times when used within `ref`s and `agent`s (interestingly this does not happen when using refs to send tasks to agents)

Comment: I wouldn't trivialize the undesirable result of things happening in an inconsistent order. 99% of the time, that's gonna bite you hard :-)

Comment: I do a pmap to retrieve a bunch of URLs in parallel... lein run works, uberjar don't. Tried doall but still doesn't work... It doesn't even work with simple map (when run as uberjar).